posgresql trigger triggers after validation of INSERT INTO
I have the following table
CREATE TABLE users(
    email citext PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL,
    quota text NOT NULL DEFAULT '10GB',
    domain citext NOT NULL
);

And the following function/trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_user_domain() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.domain := 'test.com';
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER users_domain_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_user_domain();

When I execute INSERT INTO users(email, name) VALUES ('joe@test.com', 'Joe Test');
before the insert is validated I want the trigger to set the value for domain.
Instead I get an error that domain can't be null.
The trigger is BEFORE INSERT so what is missing?

Are you sure that you set the trigger? Do you see it with '\d`?

Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461720/postgresql-before-insert-trigger-not-running-before-constraints-are-checked
I think it might be the same problem here

Your example is working without any problems on pg12 and 17.

Tested the approach in PG16, Not Null constraint is not checked before the trigger is fired. It works as expected.
Why do you need trigger for such cases, below DDL should suffice the requirement.
CREATE TABLE users(
    email citext PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL,
    quota text NOT NULL DEFAULT '10GB',
    domain citext NOT NULL default 'test.com'
);

